# How to get navigator.getUserMedia working using PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, video, html5-video

I would like to show camera live video using PhoneGap application. I have created my code base on this example - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/.

I created HTML object

```
<video autoplay></video>
```

and I created this code:

```
var errorCallback = function(e) {
   console.log('Reeeejected!', e);
};

navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                      navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                      navigator.msGetUserMedia;

var video = document.querySelector('video');

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }, errorCallback);
} else {
    cosnole.log("No media available");
}
```

The application throws no exception, the video object is created, but I can only hear audio, video is presented as a black region - no live stream is displayed. Anybody knows, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing with some plugins for a while. Once I added cordova-plugin-camera-preview and cordova-plugin-compat, my phone asked for camera permission during the installation process and I was able to see the camera preview. cordova-plugin-camera-preview adds andriod.permission.CAMERA. Unfortunately, the video is black again when the permission is added manually without the plugin.